# box flip 3D animation for side menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, menu, uiscrollview

I have scrollview and inside scrollview I have 2 views as MainView and another as SideMenuView.

What I want to make animation like below.

[image]

Any idea what needs to be done to get this working?

Comment: May be you can use side menu like this animation instead of yours. https://github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.iOS

Comment: @MeetDoshi : There are many alternate but I wanna do with this structure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Psuedo Code below:

```
- (void)animateSideMenu{
homeView.frame = CGRectMake(sideMenuWidth, 0.0, (self.view.frame.size.width - sideMenuWidth), self.view.frame.size.height);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     sideMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sideMenuWidth, sideMenuHeight);
                     [self flipAnimation];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
}

- (void)flipAnimation{
CABasicAnimation *yRotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
yRotate.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0)];
yRotate.toValue = @(M_PI * 1.5);
yRotate.duration = 0.5;
yRotate.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[sideMenu.layer addAnimation:yRotate forKey:@"yRotate"];
}
```

Below are the steps to develop this type of animation:

1. set the frame of homeView(Red colour view) of screen size & add pan gesture to this view.
2. set frame of sideMenu view in negative x-axis.
3. Create a responder function for pan gesture recogniser, in this function call the above mentioned animateSideMenu function.
4. Adjust the animation parameters accordingly.

Try with this & let me know if anything comes up.

Comment: @fahim, was that helpful to you ??

Comment: checking now... its not animating

Comment: I have to make `CABasicAnimation *yRotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];` but this is just rotation side menu which is not what i was looking for...

Comment: @FahimParkar, It's just a pseudo code you can try with different parameters to explore the possibilities it can have. yRotate.fromValue & yRotate.toValue opens more possibility once you start playing with parameters of CATransform3DMakeRotation.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a scrollview but rather a UIPanGestureRecognizer in which I would detect your current "pan offset" and calculate a current fraction of the animation and positions of those two views (let's simplify it so that the menu is view1 and the rest view2). 
Then I would simply set an appropriate transform in the .Changed state.
In .Ended state I would see whether the menu is closer to being open or close and create an animation with .toValue set accordingly. You should use CAAnimations or better - [Facebook pop](https://github.com/facebook/pop) animations because you can pause and remove them and the views stay put and not jump to their initial positions (as is often the case with UIViewAnimate).

If you need help with writing exact code you can write here and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: And if you really want to use a scroll view you can get the same values and fractions using scrollViewDidScroll.

Answer (score 1):

There's tutorial for exactly that menu, though it's in Swift: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/87268/3d-effect-taasky-swift